# Why is "when clause" past?

Tags: conditionals, when

"She said she would wait for me to return safely," he said, "and go to the frontline again with me when she recovered."

Do you know why "when clause" is past? My understanding is that it should be present because going to the frontline will happen after she recovers.

I got that sentence from the New York Times. Thank you. (https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/03/13/world/asia/coronavirus-death-life.html)

Comment: The whole statement is talking about something in the past. You can say "when she recovers" if you're planning something for the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes me a little bit confused. I wonder why they didn't use "went" instead of go.

Comment: "went" is for something that actually happened, not something that was was planned.

Comment: Thank you! I  got the point!!!